# Is it possible to deploy pretrained CNN to a machine that doesnt have nvidia GPU?

Tags: keras, deployment, gpu, conv-neural-network, pyinstaller

I have created a CNN (4 layers, so technically a deep learning model) using keras, trained it and saved the model.

I have separately created a simple GUI in Tkinter and used PyInstaller to create an application that uses that CNN.

I have tested it on the same machine I used for its development, and everything works fine. However, I have tried running it on a different machine, and it didn't work. That machine was older so I'm not really bothered about it.

However, I will need this to work on different machines. Question popped in my head, that I didn't think of before. Will I be able to run this program on a machine without NVidia GPU? Machine used for training obviously has such GPU.

I tried googling this, but nothing of essence came back. If anyone knows anything about this, I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks

Edit: I am still looking for an answer to this question so if anyone knows anything, please speak up! I will also try conducting some trials using another laptop as soon as I get my hand on it. I'll post the update once its done.

Comment: I have tested this on another laptop, without NVidia GPU, and of course there was an error about this, but it worked. 
I am still puzzled about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am positive now, that the pretrained CNN, packed with GUI in Pyinstaller works on PCs without GPU.

This has been tested of 4 different PCs now, all without dedicated GPU.

Case closed.